# Getcookie not defined

Tags: jquery, cookies

I'm using the `getcookie` value in a JQuery page. It work's on all my pages, except one, the library: https://residenciarucab.es/biblioteca/

It shows:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: getCookie is not defined
    at generic-scripts.js:2
    at dispatch (jquery.min.js:2)
    at y.handle (jquery.min.js:2)
```

JS structure:

```
function setAgreeCookie() {
    var expire=new Date();
    expire=new Date(expire.getTime()+777600000000);
    document.cookie="COOKIESCOVID19=aceptada; expires="+expire;
}

$('#acepto-normas-seguridad').click(function(){ 
    setAgreeCookie();
});

   $(window).on('load',function(){
         var myCookie = getCookie("COOKIESCOVID19");

    if (myCookie == null) {
        $('#modalcovid-footer').modal({backdrop: 'static', keyboard: false})  
    }
    else {
        // do cookie exists stuff
    }
});
```

And all the codes are on the same structure of the other pages, so it should works, but no.

Comment: Where is your `getCookie()` function declaration? - `getCookie` is not a jquery function - You need to create that yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Solved, needed to specify this:

```
  function getCookie(name) {
    var dc = document.cookie;
    var prefix = name + "=";
    var begin = dc.indexOf("; " + prefix);
    if (begin == -1) {
        begin = dc.indexOf(prefix);
        if (begin != 0) return null;
    }
    else
    {
        begin += 2;
        var end = document.cookie.indexOf(";", begin);
        if (end == -1) {
        end = dc.length;
        }
    }
    // because unescape has been deprecated, replaced with decodeURI
    //return unescape(dc.substring(begin + prefix.length, end));
    return decodeURI(dc.substring(begin + prefix.length, end));
}
```